# Шифрование методом аналитических преобразований

Tags: алгоритм, криптография

Доброго времени суток! Задали лабу, [описание](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5TsQqdlt9j1cEJZTF9XcUFjeUJyYWp4X09BLTJ0RlZMY01j/edit?usp=sharing). Такой вопрос - в примере матрица 3Х3, длина вектора 3; что делать если длина текста 8,20,200 символов? Не получится ведь разбить на векторы по 3 символа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну почему же не получится. Получится. Разбивайте на блоки кратные 3-м. Последний блок некратный 3-м дополняется до 3-х символов.

По научному такой способ в блочной криптографии называется [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) - есть множество алгоритмов как заполнять, чтобы потом при дешифровке правильно выкинуть лишние символы.

Нелишне также будет знать, что при блочном шифровании применяются т.н. режимы сцепления блоков друг-за-друга, иначе шифр легко колется т.н. атакой по маске. Подробнее про режимы сцепления [читайте здесь](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)